# Nonparametric Statistical Test to Partially Order Sample Sets

Tags: nonparametric

I am working on a program to compare the performances of players in a game.  I have an oracle that enables me to determine the points that would theoretically be lost with a minimax continuation after a move.  These numbers are originally decimal values, but I currently round and clip them so they are all integer values in the range `[0 ... max_loss]`.  I then want to use a statistical test to be able to determine whether one performance is better, worse, or similar to another performance.  If this test can provide transitive and reflexive results as required for Pareto dominance, I can use these results to cluster performances into ranked groups of similar quality.

I had been using the Mann-Whitney-U test to compare performances for many months.  I thought I had been getting good results until I got some new data recently.  Mann-Whitney-U classified a performance with no large mistakes as being equivalent to many others with sizable blunders.  Here is a chart of the performances that were clustered together since there was insufficient evidence to distinguish the sample sets:

[image: Chart comparing clustered performances]

Analyzing the Percentiles section of the chart shows that each of these performances are very similar across the 75th and lower percentiles.  The last quarter shows staggering variety.  Worse still, the Worst Mistakes section shows that most of these performances have no business being considered similar to that shown in the first column.

I tried *p*-hacking since this is not a pure research endeavor, but I had to raise *p* from 0.05 to 0.25 before some - not all - of clearly misplaced performances got bumped down.  Raising *p* further basically broke my clusters down into little clumps that were no longer helpful for comparison.

I want to find a statistical test that honors the reflexivity and transitivity of Pareto comparison.  Ideally, this test would be nonparametric, since KDE diagrams of these performances indicate that most performances are multi-modal.

Here are the tests I have found and tried:

- Epps-Singleton Test: This test proved very intuitive for comparing two performances.  It usually agreed from my instinctive comparison of two distributions.  The problem was that it only indicates that there is a difference, and not how they are different.  My attempts to follow Epps-Singleton with Mann-Whitney-U broke Pareto comparison transitivity.
- Kolmogorov-Smirnov 2-Sample Test: I have not been able to get a good feel for how well this test compares two distributions.  Not only is this test painfully slow, but its results also seem to violate Pareto comparison transitivity.

I discovered these tests through scipy.  I do not have a strong stats background, so the limited web results I get trying to seek an answer myself have been difficult to follow.

Does anyone know of a test that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Non-parametric tests basically have to violate reflexity or transivity (depending a bit on how you define 'non-parametric').

Suppose you have a test that you can always use to give a pre-order on all players (so for any players P, Q you have one of P is better than Q, Q is better than P, P and Q are indistinguishable -- it's sufficient to assume you *could* do this with enough data).

A pre-order on players implies a linear order on equivalence classes of players, and under some basic sanity conditions, a linearly ordered set has the same ordering as some subset of the reals. Thus, we can label each equivalence class by a single real number and so assign a single real number to each player that gives the ordering (or we could, with enough data). [This is basically Debreu's Theorem from economics]

So, if your test is transitive it can always be replaced by a test for some single-number summary statistic --  the mean or median or the average of the 17th and 69th percentiles or whatever.  You might be willing to describe a test for the median as 'non-parametric'; if so, that will work.

It's fairly well known that the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test is not transitive, but this argument shows there's a more general problem.